# Need help in aligning pictures with text

Tags: html, css

I have coded a website using, HTML, CSS and Jscript. In this website, in the footer section, I have placed the social site links, such as- facebook, twitter, youtube, google+, as follows:

[image: Example]

As you can see, the icons are not aligned with the text; I am asking for help in aligning them.

HTML:

```
<footer>
Find us @ 
<a href=""><img src="assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a> 
<a href=""><img src="assets/images/twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a> 
<a href=""><img src="assets/images/google+.png" alt="google plus"></a> 
<a href=""><img src="assets/images/youtube.png" alt="youtube"></a>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer                  {    
                        color: white;
                        width: 100%;
                        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        font-size: 10px;
                        background-color: black;
                        height: 30px;
                        text-align: center;
                        }


footer img              {
                        padding-top: 5px;
                        padding-bottom: 0px;
                        }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your post, and add the markup you've used to try to align the images properly.

Comment: I have edited the post and entered the codes. If possible please, do answer my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to your image CSS:

```
footer img {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Note that you may need to adjust your padding.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to align the text and icons. In addition, if you remove the height from the `footer` but give it padding you'll no longer the need to mess with the padding in order to balance it.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL5g1myw/) or the snippet below. Try changing the image height to see how the vertical centering is maintained:

```css
footer {    
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    /*height: 30px; < Remove the height, let the content hold it open and adjust it with padding*/
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px 0; /* < Add some padding here instead of on the images */
}

footer img {
    /*padding-top: 5px; < Remove this padding */
    /*padding-bottom: 0px; < Remove this padding */
    vertical-align:middle; /*< Add vertical alignment */
    height:20px; width:20px; /*< This is just for testing because the sample images dont exist. Change the height to test the verticle alignment */
}
```

```html
<footer>
Find us @ 
    <a href=""><img src="assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a> 
    <a href=""><img src="assets/images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a> 
    <a href=""><img src="assets/images/google+.png" alt="google plus" /></a> 
    <a href=""><img src="assets/images/youtube.png" alt="youtube" /></a>
</footer>
```

Alternatively you could consider using an icon font instead of images. https://icomoon.io/ is a great resource for these. Here's an example of how you might use an icon font to achieve this:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'icomoon';
 src:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1025963/icomoon/icomoon.eot?3t0141');
 src:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1025963/icomoon/icomoon.eot?#iefix3t0141') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1025963/icomoon/icomoon.woff?3t0141') format('woff'),
  url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1025963/icomoon/icomoon.ttf?3t0141') format('truetype'),
  url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1025963/icomoon/icomoon.svg?3t0141#icomoon') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
footer {    
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    /*height: 30px; < Remove the height, let the content hold it open and adjust it with padding*/
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px 0; /* < Add some padding here instead of on the images */
}
footer a {
    font-size:20px;
    color:#eee;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
 font-family: 'icomoon';
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;
 /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
footer a:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<footer>
Find us @ 
    <a href="">f</a> 
    <a href="">t</a> 
    <a href="">g</a> 
    <a href="">y</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much... I really love this code. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this: your text should have the same line-height with your icons size. Hopefully, your code is inside a wrapper, like this:

```
    <div class="some-wrapper">Find us: @ <img src="facebook.png"><img src=twitter.png"><img src="googleplus.png"><img src="youtube.png"></div>
```

In case your icons are, lets say, 16px in height, the CSS for this one will be

```
.some-wrapper {
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Mr. Designarti. I have already tried the line-height css code, but it never worked. Thanks, but I need more powerful code lines here.

Comment: whats the icon size in px?

Comment: Each of them is 17px.